# Finer control over jackson2 deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I have this class:

```
class Address {
  int id;
  String address;
  // ... other fields
}
```

I have many other classes that embed `Address`, one example:

```
class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
  Address address;
  // ... other fields
}
```

I receive a json representing a person such as:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "John",
  "addressId": 50,
  // ... other fields
}
```

I can deserialize the above into

```
class PersonJson {
  int id;
  String name;
  int addressId;
  // ... other fields
}
```

and then convert `PersonJson` into `Person`.

However, this can happen deeper in the hierarchy. I have `Organization` that has a `List<Person>`, so I'd need to have `OrganizationJson` and `List<PersonJson>` that I then need to convert to `Organization` and `List<Person>`.

Alternatively, I can make a custom deserializer for `Person`, but since `Address` is embedded in many other objects I'd have to make a deserializer for each of these. I don't think I can reuse much of this and most other fields would be deserialized by default (i.e. primitives, etc.) by `ObjectMapper`.

Both are doable, but both are a duplication of the work `ObjectMapper` already does and require maintenance in multiple places, which is a pain. Is there a way to configure `ObjectMapper` to custom-deserialize a field (including within a collection such as `List<Address>`) or some other way to avoid duplication?

Comment: One option that came to me is to use the `@JsonCreator` annotation combined with `@JsonValue` to address the deserialization back to the right entity. Let me know if this is fitable so I can answer with an example for you.

Comment: @bleidi Go for it - note that my entities are all immutable (i.e. all fields are `final`) if that matters for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first atempt that occour me is to combine the [@JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) with [@JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotations to instruct de object mapper to address (no pun intended) the deserialize to the correct nested object.

For sake of simplicity, and knowing your immutablility by you comment, there is an example below using lombok.

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.ToString;

public class JsonTest {

    @Data
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @ToString
    @Getter
    static class Address {
        int id;
        @NonNull
        String address;

        @JsonCreator
        public static Address factory(int id) {
            return new AddressBuilder().id(id).address("getAddressLogicHere").build();
        }
    }

    @Data
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Person.PersonBuilder.class)
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @ToString
    @Getter
    static class Person {
        private final int id;
        @NonNull
        private final String name;
        @JsonProperty("addressId")
        private final Address address;

        @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
        public static class PersonBuilder {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        String json = "{\n" + 
                "  \"id\": 10,\n" + 
                "  \"name\": \"John\",\n" + 
                "  \"addressId\": 50\n" + 
                "}";
        Person person = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
        //JsonTest.Person(id=10, name=John, address=JsonTest.Address(id=50, address=getAddressLogicHere))
    }

}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this though. Assume now that you have 10 more objects above that include `Address`. I'm not using Lombok, without it you'd have to write `AddressBuilder`, `PersonBulder` and all other `XXXBuilder`s., which kind of is tedious to maintain.

Comment: I see your point. I just target the solution given the question. But oppinating in your design, the resource-style of your endpoints enforce this. Instead of the builder you can also use [custom deserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) but will need equal effort.